# Why can't root access my CIFS mounts?

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab

I have a Windows CIFS share mounted through FSTAB, it mounts successfully. However I can't even DIR the folder without getting a Permission denied. I have tried adding noperm, uid and gid stuff to fstab with no results I can't even "SUDO DIR" the folder, I can't chmod or chown the folder either without a permission denied error is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from Ubuntu and not the CIFS share? e.g. have you properly authenticated to the share?

Comment: Yes I have even changed the password to be wrong and the mount fails to authenticate, if I put the right password it in mounts successfully.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to it via a graphical file manager? I've found some crash on me when browsing CIFS, but `gnome-commander` seems to do a good job with it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the CIFS share is shared on a Windows machine and mounted on Ubuntu...  If my assumption is correct, just define UID "root" with the same PWD on the Windows machine.  If not, leave a note @Fabby and I'll delete my answer...

Comment: Oh, and as you're a Reputation 1 user: if you *do* like the answer, don't bother thanking me (but feel free to add comments asking more info) but *do* accept my answer by clicking the little grey check-mark below the "0" as that will make my reputation go up...  Once you have more reputation, upvote it as well... ;-)