# Syncronizing to NAS fails but works with USB disk

Tags: sync, rsync, ubuntu-gnome, zfs

Rsync command:

```
$ rsync -ah --progress --delete /path/* 192.168.1.1:/path/
```

Gives error

```
ohto@192.168.1.1's password:  Could not chdir to home directory /var/services/homes/ohto: ... rsync: failed to set permissions on "/path": Operation not permitted (1)
```

I can copy, create, delete, modify files and folders inside NAS folder. Syncronizing with Grsync and Rsync fails.

Problem persists even after resetting and formatting the NAS.

Grsync is version 1.2.5,
Rsync is 3.1.1,
Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, Gnome 3.20.1
NAS is Synology 212j with DSM DSM 6.0-7321

How can I syncronize my files to NAS without errors?

In the end, I want to my files to be safe from cryptolockers. This is one step into that direction. I cannot achieve that goal without first getting my files to NAS.

Comment: BT sync is a bad idea for your purpose, since the encrypted files would propagate to the remote storage. Make a question about 'what is the best backup strategy against crypto locker attacks', that would be better to answer.

Comment: Yeah, it actually is. That is why now I got external USB disk in a small safe, offline. BT sync works for offsite online backup and fully automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rsync command lacks **username**, the correct rsync command in this case is

```
rsync -ah --progress --delete /path/* username@192.168.11.9:/path/
```

Appropriate username and rsync service must be enabled in NAS.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're syncing from Linux to DSM, I'd suggest using rsync directly, without first mounting the NAS destination on your desktop. There's no point letting SMB/samba sit in the middle - it will introduce extra potential problems, particularly with file naming and features not supported by SMB (such as symbolic links).

There are a lot of different ways to set this up, depending on what you want to achieve (one-off sync, regular backups etc.), and I'm not sitting in front of my NAS right now, so probably the best advice I can give is "look up rsync in the DSM help", and "tell us a bit more about what you're trying to achieve."

Comment: The achieve -bit added, rsync being studied.

Comment: Tested with rsync, does not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with zfs, but with insufficient rights for your sync programs to access the gvfs folder.

You can test this by mounting something so that `/var/run/user/1000/gvfs` is populated and then do a `sudo ls /var/run/user/1000/gvfs` and a `ls /var/run/user/1000/gvfs`. Only the last one will list the contents of the gvfs folder, the first one fails with insufficient access rights.

As evidenced by the pkexec in your post, you are trying to run them as root, which fails here. Just run them as the user.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I rather avoid perhaps a temporary solution. When I reset the NAS again, I hope to have a very simple way to sync.

Comment: Even after you reset the NAS, root won't be able to access the gvfs directory. The 'why' is unanswered http://askubuntu.com/questions/562158/why-cant-root-access-my-cifs-mounts , but it is a fact. So the answer is: It won't work by design, USB disk works because it is not CIFS mounted. Either run as user who mounted the disk or use rsync WITHOUT mounting.

Answer (score 0):

your user account ohto doesn't seem to have a sensible home directory on the remote end , this is causing a login issue and making rsync attempt to use somewhere i can't write to for temp files.

ohto is probably an account for service that has an unusual home dir , have a look in /etc/passwd to see where its home dir is.

Answer (score 0):

Against cryptolockers use for example an offline USB disk.

For online offsite automatic encrypted backup use BitTorrent Sync.

1. Install BitTorrent Sync to your computer and run it
   http://gamblisfx.com/how-to-install-bittorrent-sync-2-2-7-on-ubuntu-gnome-15-04/
2. Go to

> localhost:8888/gui

with your browser

3. Click **Menu** and select **Encrypted folder**

[image: AddFolderEnc]

4. Select the folder you want to sync and **Copy** the Encrypted key

[image: Keys]

5. Install BitTorrent Sync, or Sync, to NAS
   http://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/206215185-Synology
6. After Sync is installed, run it and click the **URL**

[image: Nas]

7. Click Menu and **Enter a key or link**
8. **Paste** the key and click **Next**
9. Select folder or create **New folder** Enc
10. Click **Open**

[image: Encfolder]

- Now, what you have in or write to folder **Unenc** will appear to folder **Enc** encrypted.
- Changes you do in **Unenc** will happen in **Enc** (but files stay encrypted)
- If you loose **Unenc** you can retrieve data from **Enc** by creating a new folder with your Read & Write key